# Swift Output Overwrites Variables

Tags: ios, swift, output

I'm working on an iOS8 project in Swift using Xcode6 Beta 3, and I'm having a problem where I can print out a variable on one line, but then the contents of that variable are replaced with what appears to be garbage.  These two consecutive lines, with absolutely no other code between them:

```
println("Data segment 0: \(dataSegments[0])")
println("Data segment 0: \(dataSegments[0])")
```

print out different values (they happen to be elements of an NSData array).  The first prints out what I expect, but the second prints out something else.

Also, if I revert to calling the function from which I get the data:

```
println("Data segment 0: \(getCharacteristicData()[0])")
println("Data segment 0: \(getCharacteristicData()[0])")
```

the first one does exactly what I expect (it prints out the same thing as the first line of the first block of code), but the second time through, getCharacteristicData() crashes with a bad access error.  Again, these lines are consecutive, with no other code executing in between.

I've been using this style output for weeks now without any problems until today.  Any ideas what might be causing this?  Is it a bug with Swift, or is there some good reason that it's destroying my data?

EDIT: I updated to beta 4.  I no longer get the bad access when I use getCharacteristicData(), but the first block of code still has the same problem.

Update: It turns out to have been a separate memory deallocation issue from elsewhere in my code, and using the variable in println() triggered the memory that had been assigned to it to be overwritten.

Comment: I recommend you update to Xcode6 Beta 4 (the latest release) and try again

Comment: Are these really successive lines, or are they successive _calls_ to println? The data really could have changed. Also, be warned - println is not thread safe. If you are doing this on a background thread you will get weird things.

Comment: They're successive lines, and I'm not working with threading.  It's all running in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Are those lines directly after each other like in your example ?

If not; chances are that you ran into the fact that swift [array immutability was broken](http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-arrays-too-swift-and-flexible-for-our-good) in the first few betas. Try upgrading to beta 4.

Comment: But array immutability was fixed in beta 3, which is what he using. How can updating to beta 4 change this?

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently upgrading to beta 4 and we'll see what that does.